# Wrong conversion using macro

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor

So I have a weird problem with a GNU GCC (C/C++) macro defined as follows:

```
#define PI                  3.14159265359
#define DEG_TO_RAD(a)       (a * PI / 180.0)
#define ARCSEC_TO_DEG(a)    (a / 3600.0)
#define ARCSEC_TO_RAD(a)    DEG_TO_RAD( ARCSEC_TO_DEG( a ) )
```

The macro, as you can tell, is simply converting a value in seconds of arc to radians. However, depending on where the macro is applied, I get a different result:

```
double xi2 = ARCSEC_TO_RAD(  2306.2181 * c + 0.30188 * c2 + 0.017998 * c3);
double xi = 2306.2181 * c + 0.30188 * c2 + 0.017998 * c3; 

printf("c = %.10f; xi = %.10f = %.10f = %.10f; ", 
       c, xi, ARCSEC_TO_RAD(xi), xi2);
```

This outputs:

```
c = 0.1899931554; xi = 438.1766743152 = 0.0021243405 = 7.6476237313;
```

Where's the silly error...?

Comment: Try expanding the macro your self. You will see that order precedence is important, e.g., `a+b/c` is not the same as `(a+b)/c`

Comment: How all that related to C++? This is exactly why macros should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Always use parentheses in macros.  Always prefer `inline` functions over macros in C++.  (Note: prefer.  I'm sure there are edge cases where macros are better.  This is not one of them.)

Comment: @Slava huh? The C++ preprocessor *is* part of C++...

Comment: @Quentin unfortunately yes, but there is no reason to use it where it can be avoided with better result.

Comment: @Slava definitely. Still, the question is very much about C++ -- it's not Python, is it ;)

Comment: @Quentin C++ is not Python, code above is not C++

Comment: Unhelpful discussion aside, I've updated the question trying to widen the scope of this question a little...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going step by step,

```
ARCSEC_TO_RAD(  2306.2181 * c + 0.30188 * c2 + 0.017998 * c3);
```

will expand to

```
DEG_TO_RAD( ARCSEC_TO_DEG(2306.2181 * c + 0.30188 * c2 + 0.017998 * c3))
DEG_TO_RAD( (2306.2181 * c + 0.30188 * c2 + 0.017998 * c3 / 3600.0))
((2306.2181 * c + 0.30188 * c2 + 0.017998 * c3 / 3600.0) * P* / 180.0)
```

Now the regular order of operations kick in here, so `2306.2181 * c + 0.30188 * c2 + 0.017998 * c3` will ***not*** be divided by 3600. Only `0.017998 * c3` will. The old school C solution is to place brackets around the macro substitutions.

The modern C and C++ solutions are to use functions. `inline` the functions if you [need to to meet ODR](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition), but the compiler will likely decide on its own whether the function should be expanded inline or not.

This question is tagged C++, so here's the C++ solution:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr double PI = 3.14159265359;
/* or
#include <cmath>
const double PI = std::acos(-1);
but I'm not certain you can properly constexpr this */

double DEG_TO_RAD(double a)
{
    return a * PI / 180.0;
}
double ARCSEC_TO_DEG(double a)
{
    return a / 3600.0;
}
double ARCSEC_TO_RAD(double a)
{
    return DEG_TO_RAD( ARCSEC_TO_DEG( a ) );
}

int main ()
{
    double c = 10;
    double c2 = 20;
    double c3 = 30;

    std::cout << DEG_TO_RAD(2306.2181 * c + 0.30188 * c2 + 0.017998 * c3) << std::endl;
}
```

In C++11 or more recent, [`constexpr` can be added](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) to make these former macros compile-time constants should it be necessary.

Comment: Why PI is still a macro?

Comment: Because I didn't think of it. Thank you. Correcting.

Comment: You missed some `(  )` and `.0` at your manual macro expansion.

Answer (score 3):

I strogly recomend you to use functions(maybe [inline](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html)), instead of MACROS,
but if for some reason you can't, a workaround could be adding parenthesis to received arguments:

```
#define PI                  3.14159265359
#define DEG_TO_RAD(a)       ((a) * PI / 180.0)
#define ARCSEC_TO_DEG(a)    ((a) / 3600.0)
#define ARCSEC_TO_RAD(a)    DEG_TO_RAD( ARCSEC_TO_DEG( (a) ) )  
//In the lastone () is not necessary but it a good prectice always adding parenthesis to macro args
```

This prevent you to have errors related to operator precedence when the macro is expanded.